# Is this the correct way to add a custom block to before_body_end only on homepage?

Tags: layout, xml, custom-block

Working with Magento CE 1.9.1.0.

I have written some custom code which I have placed here:

```
app/design/frontend/mypackage/mytheme/template/page/html/custom_code.phtml
```

I also created a new XML reference to this file here:

```
app/design/frontend/mypackage/mytheme/layout/page.xml
```

This is the reference I added within the layout block:

```
<cms_index_index>
  <reference name="before_body_end">
      <block type="core/template"  name="my_custom_code" template="template/page/html/custom_code.phtml" />
  </reference>     
</cms_index_index>
```

However after clearing cache and verifying there are no errors anywhere on the system, I still can't get the block to show before_body_end anywhere on the homepage. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template location is wrong.

Assume that your template is located at *app/design/frontend/Your_Pakage/Your_Theme/template/page/html/custom_code.phtml*.

Magento,**design fall back logic** it would be automatically at ***app/design/frontend/Your_Pakage/Your_Theme/template/***.

So you need just add `page/html/custom_code.phtml`  instead of `template/page/html/custom_code.phtml`.

Use ***`template="page/html/custom_code.phtml"`***  instead of **`template="template/page/html/custom_code.phtml"`**

Comment: Thank you Amit. I noticed that as well. I updated my reference, cleared cache and checked again but still no luck. Upvoted because it was indeed a contributing factor. is page.xml the correct place to reference my block? Should I instead be doing it in local.xml?

Comment: yes.cms_index_index only called at home. So note that ur code wil only run at home . page. If you want to run at all pages then default handler `<default>` instead of '`<cms_index_index>`

Comment: And there is no need for a module of any sort? This can be accomplished with the two files I referenced above?

Comment: no need of extension

Comment: It worked! That was it. It seemed to have been delayed by file caching. Thanks Amit.